# How can I use grep, sed, awk, or other Linux tool to search each line of a file for the sequence “\t$month\t$day\n”?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

How can I use grep, sed, awk, or other Linux tool or bash script to search each line of a file for the sequence “\t$month\t$day\n”, where…

```
\t = tab  
\n = new line  
$month = Sep   #$month is a variable with the content “Sep”  
$day = 4       #$day is a variable with the content “4”?
```

Using grep, I can find \t, \n, $month, and $day individually, but to reduce false positives, I want the tool(s) to search each line of the file for the combination “\t$month\t$day\n”, and upon a match, send the line(s) to standard output, i.e., the console.

How can I search for the combination “\t$month\t$day\n” per line of the file, and have the tool output each matching line to the console?

Example: Here are the contents of the file “start-with-core”

```
$ cat start-with-core  
core4321        Sep     3  
core.1234       Nov     4  
core4   Sep     4  
core10  Sep     4  
core11  Nov     4  
core44  Sep     2  
core400 Sep     3
```

There is one tab after the first field (column), one tab after the second, and a new line character after the third.

```
$ echo $month  
Sep  
                                                                             
$ echo $day    
4
```

```
$ grep $'\n'  start-with-core  
core4321        Sep     3  
core.1234       Nov     4  
core4   Sep     4  
core10  Sep     4  
core11  Nov     4  
core44  Sep     2  
core400 Sep     3
```

```
$ grep $'\t'  start-with-core  
core4321        Sep     3  
core.1234       Nov     4  
core4   Sep     4  
core10  Sep     4  
core11  Nov     4  
core44  Sep     2  
core400 Sep     3
```

```
$ grep "$month"  start-with-core  
core4321        Sep     3  
core4   Sep     4  
core10  Sep     4  
core44  Sep     2  
core400 Sep     3
```

```
$ grep "$day" start-with-core
core4321        Sep     3  
core.1234       Nov     4  
core4   Sep     4  
core10  Sep     4  
core11  Nov     4  
core44  Sep     2  
core400 Sep     3
```

Any ideas? Thanks! Estudiante

///\\

Comment: Do your lines **really** have trailing blank chars at the end of them? If not then please [edit] your question to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

`grep` looks for lines matching a pattern, so it seems you want to find lines that *end* in `\t$month\t$day`.

So:

```
TAB=$(printf '\t') # or TAB=$'\t' with many shells
grep "$TAB$month$TAB$day\$" < your-file
```

Where `$` (here escaped as it's otherwise use by the shell for parameter expansion, even if in most shells it's safe to leave it unescaped when followed by `"`), matches at the end of the subject.

`awk` is good for working with tabular data. You could use it to match on lines where the last field is `$day` and the second-last is `$month` with:

```
M=$month D=$day awk -F '\t' '
  $NF == ENVIRON["M"] && $(NF-1) == ENVIRON["D"]
  ' < your-file
```

`awk`'s `==` does a numeric comparison if both operands look like numbers and are not otherwise explicitly typed as strings like here, so it would match on `Sep` `4` but also on `Sep` `04`/`4.0`/`4e0`...

Comment: `+1`. Obviously given no escapes in the shell vars, as in the posted example, you could alternatively just do `awk -v m="$month" -v d="$day" -F '\t' '$NF == m && $(NF-1) == d' < your-file`.